# What is most optimal way to include data science visualizations and/or simple charts in django?

Tags: django, data-visualization

I am new in django, I have achieved to built a simple website up running in my local sever, but now I have reached that part where I want to add some cool and nice looking graphs to my project, but I see many options that are not that simple, if I could choose, I would use some python-based library or something, but it needs to load very fast. I am looking for guidance and suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: A common way to do this is with a JavaScript library like [`d3.js`](https://d3js.org/) and with AJAX calls to the (Django) backend that will fetch the data it needs to plot.

Comment: Thanks for you comments, this looks like charts.js or plotly.js, are they the same?